# Imprimir solo coincidencias en un array

Tags: java

Tengo dos arrays, uno con 20 números aleatorios y otro con esos mismos 20 números pero SIN los números que se repiten. Además, el segundo array está ordenado  de forma ascendente. Mi intención es imprimir los números sin repeticiones pero con el orden que tenían los 20 números aleatorios. Espero haberme explicado bien. Esto es lo que tengo por ahora.
EDIT: Los 20 números son pedidos por teclado. Estos 20 números son los que contiene el primerer array

```
int[] entrada = new int[20];
```

Este array lo he duplicado para poder compararlo al extraerle los números repetidos en otro método(no creo que haga falta poner el método)

```
int[] duplicado = new int[20]
for (int i = 0; i<entrada.length; i++){
    duplicado[i] = entrada[i];
}
```

Y esto es lo que he intentado para imprimir solo los números sin repeticiones y por el orden que ha introducido el usuario::

```
for (int i = 0; i<duplicado.length; i++){
     int j = 0;
     if(duplicado[i] == entrada[j]){    
          System.out.println(duplicado[i]);
     }else{
          j++;
     }

}
```

Comment: Podrías colocar ambos array, (aunque sean menos datos) pero seria para tener una mejor idea; adicional si de esos array pudieras colocar el resultado esperado, facilitas mas conseguir una buena respuesta.

Comment: @CesarRomero Ya lo he modificado, espero que se entienda mejor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De la manera que lo estás haciendo no estas recorriendo bien los array. Me explico:

Empiezas a recorrer el array duplicado y miras que `duplicado[0]` sea igual a `entrada[0]`.

Si no son iguales, `j` es `j++` por lo que `j=1`. Además el for sigue adelante por lo que en la siguiente pasada estas mirando que  `duplicado[1]` sea igual a `entrada[1]`.

Y en la siguiente miras que `duplicado[2]` sea igual a `entrada[2]`.

Esto hace que no compares todos con todos. Para conseguir lo que quieres necesitas tener dos sentencias `for`. El código sería así:

```
ArrayList<Integer> imprimidos = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i<duplicado.length; i++){
     for (int j = 0; j<entrada.length; j++){
         if(duplicado[i] == entrada[j] && !imprimidos.contains(entrada[j])){    
              System.out.println(duplicado[i]);
              imprimidos.add(duplicado[i]);
         }
     }
}
```

Con los dos `for` vas mirando en la posición `duplicado[i]` posición por posición (0,1,2,3,4,etc.) y los comparas con todas las posiciones del array `entrada[j]`.

Para mejor código, si sólo quieres encontrar una sola coincidencia y que pare de seguir buscando (ya que lo ha encontrado una vez) puedes añadir un `return` en el `if` para que busque la siguiente.

```
ArrayList<Integer> imprimidos = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i<duplicado.length; i++){
     for (int j = 0; j<entrada.length; j++){
         if(duplicado[i] == entrada[j]  && !imprimidos.contains(entrada[j])){    
              System.out.println(duplicado[i]);
              imprimidos.add(duplicado[i]);
              return;
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Efectivamente este bucle recorre el array, pero lo que necesito es que al recorrer el array omita los valores repetidos. Es decir, que use sólamente use los valores de "entrada" pero con el orden de "duplicado". Al igual tengo que plantearme el problema de otra manera.

Comment: Te he añadido un array que guarda los valores imprimidos. Con la función includes() miro a ver si se ha imprimido y en el caso de que sea falso imprime, sino no.

Comment: Me temo que no puedo utilizar .includes ni .push, ¿se pueden usar en java? He buscado pero sólo me salen ejemplos de javascript.

Comment: Perdón, me he liado de lenguaje...

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que entiendo ya tienes el el array Duplicado los números sin duplicados y ordenados por orden ascendente, entonces lo que tendrías que hacer para imprimir los no duplicados en el orden original es recorrer el array de entrada buscando si los números están en el array duplicado, y en caso de que estén lo imprimes y continuas con la ejecución, sino simplemente pasas de hacer nada por que es un número duplicado.

Es decir, algo así:

```
    for (int i = 0; i<entrada.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < duplicado.length; j++){
            if (entrada[i] == duplicado[j]){
                System.out.println(duplicado[i]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```